# Uniqueness of the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does $y^{'}=1+y^2+3\sin^2 y$ have

unique solution and what is the maximal intervals of existence of solutions of initial value problems for these scalar differential equation?

Comment: When speaking about a unique solution, it is in the context of a particular solution to an initial value problem (and not just some general ODE). The standard condition for existence and uniqueness in an interval is that the RHS of your equation is Lipschitz in $y$ (which it is, in any closed and bounded interval) and continuous in $x$ (which doesn't even appear in the equation).

Comment: It seems to me that your question is equivalent to calculating
$\int (1 + y^2 + 3\sin^2 y) dy.~$ This is a straight integration
problem where the only possible trouble is $\int \sin^2 y dy$.
This is easily disposed of by recognizing that 
$\cos (2y) = \cos^2 y - sin^2 y = 1 - 2\sin^2 y$.
Thus, the problem reduces to $\int \cos(2y) dy$, which should be
straight forward.

Comment: @user2661923 the question asks us to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{1+y^2+3\sin^2(y)}dy$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the alternative problem of $y' = 1 + y^2$ would be interpreted as $x = g(y)$, and $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + y^2$, so therefore $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{1 + y^2}.$  Is my understanding of what you are indicating correct?

Comment: yes you are correct @user2661923

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Thanks again for your attention, If I understand correctly, 
in order to interpret $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ as equivalent to $\frac{1}{(dx/dy)},$
you need something like $x = G(y), y=F(x),$ where $G$ is the inverse of $F$ and
$G'(y) = [1/F'(x)].$  This means that even if you could integrate (or approximate)
$G(y)$ you **then** would **also** have to identify a domain for $G$ so that it is 
1-1 in this domain.  Is this also correct, or have I gone too far?